# Simplify long if-else chain with regex by comparing with array

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, if-statement

```
for (my $j = 0; $j <100000; $j++){
    my $outcome = rand();
    for (my $k = 0; $k < @cum_sum; $k++){
        if ($cum_sum[$k] >= $outcome){
            if ($keys[$k] =~ m/\"|\/|\<|\>|\\|\`|\~|\@|\#|\$|\%|\^|\*|[0-9]/) {
                print $out "";
            }
            if ($keys[$k] =~ m/\s/){
                print $out " ";
            }
            elsif ($keys[$k] =~ m/\&/){
                print $out " and ";
            }
            elsif ($keys[$k] =~ m/\!/){
                print $out "! ";
            }
            elsif ($keys[$k] =~ m/\:/){
                print $out ": ";
            }
            elsif ($keys[$k] =~ m/\'/){
                print $out "' ";
            }
            elsif ($keys[$k] =~ m/\./){
                print $out ". ";
            }
            elsif ($keys[$k] =~ m/\;/){
                print $out "; ";
            }
            elsif ($keys[$k] =~ m/\?/){
                print $out "? ";
            }
            elsif ($keys[$k] =~ m/\,/){
                print $out ", ";
            }
            else {
                print $out "$keys[$k]";
            }
            last;
        }
    }
#   print "$outcome\n";
}
```

I mostly need help with simplifying the long chain of `elsif` statements I have. 
The logic in the outer for loops works.
`@keys` is an array of two character (digrams) strings.

I am trying to make the `elsif` statements more efficient by comparing the digrams from `@key` to an array of the punctuation marks `@punctuation = qw(! : " ' ; ? , .)`

Then, if the digram does contain one of the punctuation marks in the punctuation array, the digram gets changed to "punctuation_mark " e.g. "a!" -> "! "

The end result would be that I do not use regexes for any of `@punctuation`.

However, I am not sure on how to implement this change.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use alternation, just like in the first regex, but capture the match and [use `$1`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Extracting-matches) to replace the word

```
my $re_punct = join '|', map { quotemeta } qw(& ! : ' . ; ? ,);  #'

for my $j (0..99_999) {
    my $outcome = rand();
    for my $k (0..$#cum_sum) {
        ...    
        if ($keys[$k] =~ /($re_punct)/) { 
            if ($1 eq '&') { $keys[$k] = " and " }
            else           { $keys[$k] = "$1 "   }             
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comments

- [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) escapes by `\` all "*ASCII non-"word" characters*"
- syntax: `$#ary` is the index of the last element in `@ary`, just right for looping over array index
- `for my $i ($beg .. $end)` is much clearer than the equivalent C-style `for` loop<sup>†</sup>

The presented logic leaves a question: what if both characters are punctuation?

---

Note on your idea to do it "*By Comparing With Array*"

You could use [List::MoreUtils::first_value](http://search.cpan.org/%7Erehsack/List-MoreUtils-0.426/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm#first_value_BLOCK_LIST), for instance. It would go like

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(first_value);

my @punc = map { quotemeta }  qw(& ! : ' . ; ? ,);  #'

foreach my $word (@words) {
    if (my $match = first_value { $word =~ /$_/ } @punct) {
        $word = $match;
    }
}
```

The `first_value` (or `firstval`) returns the first element of `@punct` for which the block returns true, and `undef` if none do. The `$word` aliases the currently processed element of `@words` and changing it changes the array element; so you get your  replacement.

However, you still have to deal with regex and escape (at least some of) punctuation. Thus I see no advantage in going to this trouble; the "straight-up" regex is far clearer in this case.

---

<sup>†</sup> Even compiled languages evolve this way. The `C++11` introduced the [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

```c++
for (auto var: container) ...  // (really, const auto&), or auto&, or auto&&
```

and a standard reference linked above says

> Used as a more readable equivalent to the traditional `for` loop  [...]

In Perl this is how things are done; just use it.

Comment: Yeah, the range based for loop is more readable. I'll try to implement it in the future.

Comment: @NinJesus In case I didn't phrase it right: I meant this as a further support for using it in Perl, where there is nothing to it. (In C++ it does take a little work to start using it.)

Answer (score 2):

In order to simplify your code, it may have sense to use the [Tie::RegexpHash](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::RegexpHash) CPAN module. The main idea is build a hash with regexpr as keys, so you easily find the related values by matching:

```
use Tie::RegexpHash;
my $rehash = Tie::RegexpHash->new();

$rehash->add( qr/\s/, " " );
$rehash->add( qr/\&/, " and " );
#...

my $value = $rehash->match( "&" );  # $value <-- " and "
```

Answer (score 0):

So, looking at it you have two cases:

One where you replace a set of values, with 'the value and a space'.  And another where you replace with something different.

So how about creating a lookup table for each, and processing just two regexes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl.

use strict;
use warnings; 
use Data::Dumper;

my %replace = ( 
    '"' => "",
    '/' => "",
    '&' => " and ",
);
my @add_space = ( ',', '?',  ';', '.', "'", ':', '!' );

my $search = join ( "|", map { quotemeta } keys %replace ); 
   $search = qr/($search)/;        

my $add_space_after = join "|", map {quotemeta} @add_space; 
   $add_space_after = qr/($add_space_after)/; 


while ( <DATA> ) {
    s/\s/ /g;
    s/$search/$replace{$1}/; 
    s/$add_space_after/$1 /;
    print;
}

__DATA__
Work:Work
cookies&milk;wordhere
why?are;you/so "sad"
```

This gives us what you want I think, and - hopefully - keeps the code pretty conscise.

Of importance is the `quotemeta` function here, because it ensures your metachars are escaped before regexing them.

Note - the only one of your examples this *doesn't* handle is the `\s` to " ". But that's IMO probably best to write separately for clarity, as obviously youc can't `quotemeta` it.